# spring boot soap client issue

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-boot

After fallowing few tutorials I was trying to consume

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?wsdl

Here is my project Structure

[image: Her]

CurrenciesConfig has

```
@Configuration
public class CurrenciesConfig {

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        // this is the package name specified in the <generatePackage> specified in
        // pom.xml
        marshaller.setContextPath("com.example.soaptest.soapEntities");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public SOAPConnector soapConnector(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        SOAPConnector client = new SOAPConnector();
        client.setDefaultUri("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/");

        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate(SOAPConnector soapConnector){
       return soapConnector.getWebServiceTemplate();
    }
```

pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <generatePackage>com.example.soaptest.soapEntities</generatePackage>
                    <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaIncludes>
                        <include>*.wsdl</include>
                    </schemaIncludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

SomeClass is class where I am actually making soap call

```
@Service
public class SomeClass {

    private static final ObjectFactory WS_CLIENT_FACTORY = new ObjectFactory();

    @Autowired
    private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void dosomething(){

        CelsiusToFahrenheit celsiusToFahrenheit = WS_CLIENT_FACTORY.createCelsiusToFahrenheit();
        celsiusToFahrenheit.setCelsius("100");
        CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse celsiusToFahrenheitResponse = (CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(celsiusToFahrenheit);

        celsiusToFahrenheitResponse.getCelsiusToFahrenheitResult();
    }
}
```

I am getting below Error while executing it

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'someClass': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create message from InputStream: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:139) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1691) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.example.soaptest.config.SoaptestApplication.main(SoaptestApplication.java:16) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create message from InputStream: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:216) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:60) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:92) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:611) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:383) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:373) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.example.soaptest.config.SomeClass.dosomething(SomeClass.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:309) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.identifyContentType(MessageImpl.java:655) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.<init>(MessageImpl.java:301) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl.<init>(Message1_1Impl.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl.createMessage(SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl.java:63) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:188) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

I have tried to many combinations still getting such errors.

Where is issue ?

Comment: I doubt that `https://www.w3schools.com/xml/` is the actual SOAP service you want to call.

Comment: I have changed it `https://www.w3schools.com/xml/asmx` then `https://www.w3schools.com/xml/CelsiusToFahrenheit' still was not through

Comment: As stated I highly doubt that the sample web service is located at that URL. The URL is in the WSDL, check it and use that URL. Hint the service URL is probably the same as you use the obtain the WSDL but without the `?wsdl`.

Comment: `https://www.w3schools.com/xml/CelsiusToFahrenheit` is generated in stub with wsimport and also tried with soapUI & action url was same. Also documentation here `https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit` shows same

Comment: You ren't using the stub, you are using Spring WS... That is nice bit your configuration doesn't reflect that. You use `https://www.w3schools.com/xml` and not `https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx`.

Comment: when I change to `https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx` it gives `Caused by: org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: .`

Comment: Because you aren't setting the `SOAPAction` header in your client.

Comment: `CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse celsiusToFahrenheitResponse = (CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(celsiusToFahrenheit,new SoapActionCallback("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/CelsiusToFahrenheit"));` solved it. Thanks